# How to send mail to all emails in my database table?

Tags: php, email

I tried with this code to send emails to people with the same category.

```
if ($action = 'message_til_flere') {
        $vagt_ansat_email = $_POST['vagt_ansat_email'];

        $select_alle_mails = " SELECT vagt_ansat_email FROM vagt_ansat_med_kategori WHERE vagt_kategori_id = $id ";

        $til_vagter = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_alle_mails)) {
            $til_vagter[] = $row['vagt_ansat_email'];

        $to = $til_vagter;

        $subject = "E-mail subject";
        $headers = 'From: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', $til_vagter) . "\r\n";
    }
         mail($to, $subject, $headers);
```

Comment: you haven't told us what happens? and "*it does not work*" is not an acceptable answer

Comment: array(3) { ["page"]=> string(12) "kontrolpanel" ["action"]=> string(17) "message_til_flere" ["vagt_ansat_email"]=> string(0) "" } Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/alex.wi1/public_html/security_report/admin/sites/kontrolpanel.php on line 268

Comment: thats the messege i get sry for not telling Dagon i wil be better for it from now on pormice

Answer (score 1):

$to couldn't be an array. It has to be a string. Multiple mailadresses have to be comma seperated. To do this, you could use the php function [implode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php)

```
$to = implode(',', $til_vagter);
```

**Example:**

```
if ($action = 'message_til_flere') {
    $vagt_ansat_email = $_POST['vagt_ansat_email']; // never used in this part

    $select_alle_mails = " SELECT vagt_ansat_email FROM vagt_ansat_med_kategori WHERE vagt_kategori_id = $id ";

    $til_vagter = array();
    $result = mysql_query($select_alle_mails); // a connection to db is required
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // fetch results as array
        $til_vagter[] = $row['vagt_ansat_email'];
    }

    $to = "myemailadress@mywebsite.tld";

    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $headers = 'From: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', $til_vagter) . "\r\n";
    $message = "Test Body";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // a message is required
}
```

Comment: hes also doing that in the BCC, so has to drop that

Comment: Did the user know from each other? Well, when not it's the better solution to send in BCC and use just an placeholder mailadress for $to like mail@yourdomain.com

Comment: Can you give an xample pls php site is hard to understand :=)

Comment: or send mail one at a time in the loop

Comment: U ment $to = 'Anemail@mail.com?'

Comment: yes, that is what i ment. Sorry

Comment: i tryed that now but stil dont get it send, like $to = empty hmm

Comment: hehe im all new to this now i see you code ill try

Comment: i send a smile hehe:)

Comment: $to doesn't be empty. You could use for test your own mailadress (or make an gmail-account like mywebpagename@gmail.com) or change it to the solution from @Dagon.

Comment: either way, until you actually run the query, your not going to get far.

Comment: @alexcodex in your code-snippet above the mail-function has no mail-messag param. The method signature is mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Answer (score 1):

I personally would send one mail at a time in the loop like so:

```
if ($action = 'message_til_flere') {
 //   $vagt_ansat_email = $_POST['vagt_ansat_email']; //not used?

    $select_alle_mails = " SELECT vagt_ansat_email FROM vagt_ansat_med_kategori WHERE vagt_kategori_id = $id ";

    //RUN QUERY
$sel_result = mysql_query($select_alle_mails); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel_result)) {


    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $headers = 'From: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
     $message="dear bob, having fun?";
     mail($row['vagt_ansat_email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
```

Comment: how do i throw up a picture again ?

Comment: if ($action = 'message_til_flere') {
 //   $vagt_ansat_email = $_POST['vagt_ansat_email']; //not used?

    $select_alle_mails = " SELECT vagt_ansat_email FROM vagt_ansat_med_kategori WHERE vagt_kategori_id = $id ";

    $sel_result = mysql_query($select_alle_mails);
    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_alle_mails)) {


    $subject = "E-mail subject";
    $headers = 'From: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
    $message="dear bob, having fun?";
     mail($row['vagt_ansat_email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
}

Comment: sorry bout the small text

Comment: your running the while on the wrong variable, see above. also i don't know what you mean about *"how do i throw up a picture again ?"*

Comment: yes, a loop would be better, perhaps 2, one to retrieve the data, close connection then second one to send

Answer (score 1):

You did not execute the query prior to fetching, and you passed the query string to `mysql_fetch_array()` that is not correct. it is the result of the query you need to fetch:

```
    $select_alle_mails = "SELECT vagt_ansat_email 
                          FROM vagt_ansat_med_kategori 
                          WHERE vagt_kategori_id = $id ";

    $result = mysql_query($select_alle_mails);
    $til_vagter = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {...}
```

- mysql_ is deprecated
- use prepared statement
- <strike>I'm not sure if `mail()` has a limit on the recipient, but</strike> it sounds like you should send them in batch
- See `@vonHergen` and `@dagon` for other things to fix

Comment: mail, has no limit, mail servers do, and each mail server is different (its a pain) I think get it working then make him change db api :-)

Comment: that's what I thought, OP better send them in batches

Comment: i suggested one at a time in the loop, in my answer

Comment: tahnk you all alot for you help so far i havnt solved it yet but the day wil com when i do you werry kind al to help me ty and su tomorrow my head gonna xplode hehe :=)

Comment: array(3) { ["page"]=> string(12) "kontrolpanel" ["action"]=> string(17) "message_til_flere" ["vagt_ansat_email"]=> string(0) "" } Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user '' (using password: NO) in /home/alex.wi1/public_html/ on line 267 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/alex.wi1/public_html/ on line 267 Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/alex.wi1/public_html/security_report/admin/sites/kontrolpanel.php on line 269

Comment: here you go, first get the database connection working nothing would work without it

Comment: array(3) { ["page"]=> string(12) "kontrolpanel" ["action"]=> string(17) "message_til_flere" ["vagt_ansat_email"]=> string(0) "" } Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/alex.wi1/public_html/security_report/admin/sites/kontrolpanel.php on line 269

Comment: code now         

      $select_alle_mails = " SELECT vagt_ansat_email FROM vagt_ansat_med_kategori WHERE vagt_kategori_id = $id ";
        $resultto = $objCrud->select($sql);
//        $resultto = mysql_query($select_alle_mails);
    $til_vagter = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultto))

        $subject = "E-mail subject";
        $headers = 'From: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', $til_vagter) . "\r\n";
    }
         mail($to, $subject, $headers);
 }

Comment: Try `$result = mysql_query($select_alle_mails) or die("error = ".mysql_error());`

Comment: array(3) { ["page"]=> string(12) "kontrolpanel" ["action"]=> string(17) "message_til_flere" ["vagt_ansat_email"]=> string(0) "" } error =

Comment: what is this array dump?

Comment: $select_alle_mails = " SELECT vagt_ansat_email FROM vagt_ansat_med_kategori WHERE vagt_kategori_id = $id ";
        $resultto = $objCrud->select($select_alle_mails);
//        $resultto = mysql_query($select_alle_mails);
   
    $til_vagter = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultto))

        $subject = "E-mail subject";
        $headers = 'From: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: mywebpage' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', $til_vagter) . "\r\n";
    }
         mail($to, $subject, $headers);
 }

Comment: @alexcodex did you fix the connection

Comment: yes i believe so :=)

Comment: cus now it says array(3) { ["page"]=> string(12) "kontrolpanel" ["action"]=> string(17) "message_til_flere" ["vagt_ansat_email"]=> string(0) "" } Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/alex.wi1/public_html/security_report/admin/sites/kontrolpanel.php on line 270

Comment: I must go now, the scool i calling tommorow early i thank you for the help so far have a good night :)

Comment: @alexcodex Hi are you still having trouble

Comment: @meda hi yer im still having trouble with it :=)